# how to set combobox id from the store data received in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am having a combobox in my formpanel. Initially I used that form for Adding new information about company to my database.

Now I am having grid containing information about the company, when I click on it based on the Id query is made and it returns the full information about the company store.

with this all data **I am also getting the id of the combobox country, state, city and I am not able to set the values of my combobox based on country id, state id, city id received**.

**my json companydata is below mentioned**

```
    {
    "companydata": [{
        "city": {
            "cityname": "Patna",
            "stateid": 2,
            "cityid": 2,
            "cityzipcode": null
        },
        "cmpname": "Kintu Designs Pvt ltd",
        "cmptitle": "Kintu Designs Pvt ltd",
        "cmpcontact": "8128812153",
        "cmpdesc": "<b>?Kintu designs Surat</b>",
        "cmpfax": "8128812153",
        "cmpwebsite": "www.kintudesigns.com",
        "cmpemail1": "yaryan997@gmail.com",
        "cmpemail2": "yaryan997@gmail.com",
        "cmplogo": "calendar.png",
        "cmplogopath": "upload/images/",
        "cmpaddress": "Kintu designs Surat",
        "cmpcreatedby": 1,
        "cmpcreatedon": 1199932743000,
        "cmpmodifiedon": 1199932743000,
        "cmpmodifiedby": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "state": {
            "statename": "Bihar",
            "countryid": 1,
            "stateid": 2
        },
        "country": {
            "countryid": 1,
            "countryname": "India"
        }
    }],
    "total": 1,
    "success": true
}
```

now based on it I want to set the values of my edit form. All the values has been set perfectly, only the combobox values are not setting perfectly.

**my edit window code is below**

```
Ext.define('rms.view.companymgt.companyEdit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.companyeditwindow',
    id: 'companyeditwindow',
    editform:1,
    itemId: 'companyeditwindow',
    store: 'companyStore',
    constrain: true,
    height: 595,
    width: 875,
    layout: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: 'Company',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    itemId: 'editmainform',
                    frame: true,
                    height: 546,
                    margin: 2,
                    width: 838,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    preventHeader: true,
                    title: 'My Form',
                    items: [
                    {

                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        height: 134,
                        margin: 2,
                        width: 400,
                        title: 'Company Information',
                        items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmptitle',
                            itemId: 'cmptitle',
                            margin: 5,
                            width: 366,
                            name: 'cmptitle',
                            fieldLabel: 'Company Title',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmpname',
                            itemId: 'cmpname',
                            margin: 5,
                            name: 'cmpname',
                            fieldLabel: 'Company Name',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmpwebsite',
                            itemId: 'cmpwebsite',
                            margin: 5,
                            name: 'cmpwebsite',
                            fieldLabel: 'Website',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    height: 138,
                    margin: 2,
                    width: 400,
                    title: 'Company Contact',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmpfax',
                            itemId: 'cmpfax',
                            margin: 5,
                            name: 'cmpfax',
                            fieldLabel: 'Fax No',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmpcontact',
                            itemId: 'cmpcontact',
                            margin: 5,
                            name: 'cmpcontact',
                            fieldLabel: 'Contact No',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmpemail1',
                            itemId: 'cmpemail1',
                            margin: 5,
                            name: 'cmpemail1',
                            fieldLabel: 'Email',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'cmpemail2',
                            itemId: 'cmpemail2',
                            margin: 5,
                            name: 'cmpemail2',
                            fieldLabel: 'Other Email',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    height: 350,
                    margin: 2,
                    width: 397,
                    title: 'Company Address',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 'btn-add-country',
                            itemId: 'btn-add-country',
                            xtype: 'button',
                            margin: '4 0 0 303',
                            style: 'position:absolute;',
                            width: 71,
                            text: 'Add Country',
                            action: 'btn-add-country'
                        },
                        {
                             xtype: 'combobox',
                            id: 'countryname',
                            itemId: 'countryname',
                            name: 'countryid',
                            margin: 5,
                            width: 294,
                            fieldLabel: 'Country',
                            emptyText: 'Select Country...',
                            displayField: 'countryid',
                            store: 'country',
                            valueField: 'countryid'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'btn-add-state',
                            itemId: 'btn-add-state',
                            margin: '0 0 0 303',
                            style: 'position:absolute;',
                            width: 71,
                            text: 'Add State',
                            action: 'btn-add-state'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            id: 'statename',
                            itemId: 'statename',
                            margin: 5,
                            width: 294,
                            name: 'stateid',
                            fieldLabel: 'State',
                            emptyText: 'Select State...',
                            displayField: 'stateid',
                            store: 'state',
                            valueField: 'stateid'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'btn-add-city',
                            itemId: 'btn-add-city',
                            xtype: 'button',
                            margin: '0 0 0 303',
                            style: 'position:absolute;',
                            width: 71,
                            text: 'Add City',
                            action: 'btn-add-city'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            id: 'cityname',
                            itemId: 'cityname',
                            margin: 5,
                            width: 294,
                            name: 'cityid',
                            fieldLabel: 'City',
                            emptyText: 'Select City...',
                            displayField: 'cityid',
                            store: 'city',
                            valueField: 'cityid'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            height: 75,
                            id: 'cmpaddress',
                            itemId: 'cmpaddress',
                            margin: 5,
                            width: 380,
                            name: 'cmpaddress',
                            fieldLabel: 'Address',
                            anchor: '100%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'htmleditor',
                            height: 146,
                            id: 'cmpdesc',
                            itemId: 'cmpdesc',
                            margin: 5,
                            style: 'background-color: white;',
                            name: 'cmpdesc',
                            fieldLabel: 'Description',
                            hideLabel: true,
                            anchor: '100%'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    height: 350,
                    margin: 2,
                    width: 398,
                    title: 'Company Logo',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'form',
                            frame: true,
                            itemId: 'logoform',
                            id: 'logoform',
                            height: 320,
                            width: 375,
                            bodyPadding: 10,
                            preventHeader: true,
                            title: 'My Form',
                            items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'image',
                                        height: 158,
                                        itemId: 'cmplogoimg',
                                        margin: 10,
                                        width: 287,
                                        src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/sencha-large.png'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'filefield',
                                        margin: '10 0 0 15',
                                        width: 296,
                                        name: 'file',
                                        id: 'file',
                                        itemId: 'file',
                                        fieldLabel: 'File',
                                        labelWidth: 50,
                                        msgTarget: 'side',
                                        allowBlank: false,
                                        emptyText: 'Select file',
                                        buttonText: 'Select a File...'
                                    }],

                                dockedItems: [{
                                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                                    dock: 'bottom',
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'tbfill'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            text: 'Upload',
                                            handler: function() {
                                                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                                                alert('VALUE IS :'+form.getValues());
                                                if(form.isValid()){
                                                    form.submit({
                                                        url: 'company/UploadFile.action',
                                                        waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                                                        success: function(fp, o) {
                                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file has been uploaded.');
                                                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                              url: 'company/GetImages.action',
                                                              scope: this,
                                                              success: function(response,opts) {
                                                                    console.log('GET IMAGES');
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }

                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'tbseparator'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            text: 'Reset',
                                            itemId: 'btn-reset',
                                            action: 'btn-reset'
                                            ,
                                            handler: function() {
                                                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    height: 27,
                    width: 804,
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'tbfill'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Save',
                            action: 'btn-save-company'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'tbseparator'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Exit',
                            action: 'btn-exit-company'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
          }
        ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**my controller function that executes when the grid is clicked**

```
editCompany: function(grid, no, rowindex,colindex,temp) {  
        alert('EDIT COMPANY BUTTON PRESSED');
        var rec = this.getCompanyDetail().store.getAt(rowindex);
        console.log(rec);
        var actionid = grid.getCellByPosition( {row:rowindex,column:colindex } ).id;    
        this.getCompanyEdit().animateTarget=actionid;
        this.getCompanyEdit().editform=1;
        //this.getCompanyEditForm().getForm().reset();
        this.getCompanyEditForm().loadRecord(rec);                  
        this.getCompanyEdit().show();
    },
```

**my company store is**

```
Ext.define('rms.store.company', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'rms.model.companyModel',
storeId: 'companyStore',
autoLoad: true,
 proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read : 'company/GetCompany.action',
        create : 'company/CreateCompany.action',
        update: 'company/UpdateCompany.action',
        destroy: 'company/DeleteCompany.action'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'companydata',
        totalProperty: 'total',
        successProperty: 'success'

    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: true,
        root: 'companydata'
    }
}
```

});

**and my company model is**

```
Ext.define('rms.model.companyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [
          { name: 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true, mapping: 'id'},
          { name: 'cmpname', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpname'},
          { name: 'cmptitle', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmptitle'},
          { name: 'cmpdesc', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpdesc'},
          { name: 'cmpfax', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpfax'},
          { name: 'cmpcontact', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpcontact'},
          { name: 'cmpwebsite', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpwebsite'},
          { name: 'cmpemail1', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpemail1'},
          { name: 'cmpemail2', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpemail2'},
          { name: 'countryname', type: 'int', mapping: 'country'},
          { name: 'statename', type: 'int', mapping: 'state'},
          { name: 'cityname', type: 'int', mapping: 'city'},
          { name: 'cmplogo', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmplogo'},
          { name: 'cmplogopath', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmplogopath'},
          { name: 'cmpaddress', type: 'string', mapping: 'cmpaddress'},
      ]
```

});

**and from the server response I am receiving the countryid, stateid, cityid. But I am not able to set the combobox with the id I had received.**
Please help me to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your store 'country' and how is it defined?

Comment: I had updated my question. Please suggest me some solution I can try to get my problem solved

Comment: Where do you load your stores for comboboxes? Remember that load procedure is async and it can be simply still loading when you load your other store values to the form

Comment: I had update my question and added companyStore and companyModel. Please see it and help me to set combobox for country, state, city in EditWindow

Comment: Your country/state/city stores are most likely not loaded.

Comment: I am having four store and the company,country,state,city. and my company store returns me proper data to be set on the country combobox but still not able to set the combobox correctly

Comment: It's all about the timing. I think by the time you load your form - other stores are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your comboboxes loaded with the list of all store models and the one you are passing selected or do you want it to contain only the one you are passing?

Also, try setting in each combobox item the property `queryMode: local` just in case...

Comment: I am having four stores countryStore for country combo, stateStore for state combo, cityStore for city combo, and companyStore for company. When i click the company grid list it opens the EditCompany window. I am getting my json data from the server response as above but still not able to set the combobox for country,state and city in my edit window. Please suggest me some solution i am stuck here

Comment: did you try setting each combo with `queryMode:local`?

Comment: Did you try setting each combo with `queryMode:local`?
I would also suggest you to use in each combobox definition (this how I do it and it works for me)
`store: Ext.StoreManager.Lookup('company')` 
instead of 
`store: 'company'`

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand if you can't populate the comboboxes or if the comboboxes are populated but you can't make the corresponding item selected.